# Error when adding 2-D array and 2-D subarray of 3-D array in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

Why does Julia throw an error when I run the following code?
After all, `A[1,:,:]` is logically a 2-D array.
If I remember correctly, similar code would have worked in MATLAB.

```
julia> A = reshape(1:8, 2, 2, 2)
2x2x2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  3
  2  4

[:, :, 2] =
 5  7
 6  8

julia> B = reshape(1:4, 2, 2)
2x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  3
 2  4

julia> B + A[1,:,:]
ERROR: dimensions must match
 in promote_shape at operators.jl:211
 in promote_shape at operators.jl:207
 in + at array.jl:723
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `A` and `B` as defined in your question, note that:

```
ndims(B)
ndims(A[1,:,:])
```

returns `2` and `3` respectively. So a sum operation fails because `B` is a matrix while `A[1,:,:]` is a 3-dimensional array. Specifically, `A[1,:,:]` is `1x2x2`. The solution is to `squeeze` the first dimension like so:

```
B + squeeze(A[1,:,:], 1)
```

I can see the source of the confusion here. I'm guessing you noticed that:

```
B[1, :]
```

returns type `Vector`, and you assumed the same principle of automatic squeezing would apply to a higher-dimensional array. The github issues page where the questions surrounding this kind of behaviour were settled is [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/231). Interesting read.